# Is it possible for a US citizen to apply for a visa for Japan from South Korea?

Tags: visas, japan, international-travel, us-citizens, south-korea

I am a US citizen and I'm going to be studying abroad in Japan in April, 2017.
I want to visit Seoul, South Korea for a couple month before then.

Is it possible to apply for the visa for Japan while I'm in South Korea?

Has anyone been in a similar situation? What is the recommended approach to doing this? (I was leaning more towards taking care of everything by mail, but I'm not sure).

Comment: You should ask the Japanese embassy in Korea whether they will accept your application.

Comment: Why not just do it at the Consulate nearest to you? That might be easier than carrying the [documentation required for a student visa](http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/visa/study-college.html). What would you do if there's an issue?

Comment: If all else fails, it's also possible to obtain a residence permit after enteirng Japan

Answer (score 4):

From the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Japan](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/faq.html):

**Q5: Can I apply for a visa at the nearest Japanese Embassy / Consulate General while traveling in a foreign country?**

A5: You can apply for the visa at the Japanese Embassy / Consulate General in your own country (region) or country (region) of residence (if there is more than one, apply to the Japanese Embassy / Consulate General nearest from where you live). In other words, you cannot apply for a visa at your travel destination; however, if there are unavoidable circumstances, consult with the Japanese Embassy / Consulate General where you would like to apply for the visa before making the application.